# Cannot uninstall ionic

Tags: npm, ionic2, nvm, ionic3

I currently have installed on my mac ionic version 2.2.1
When I try to run on the terminal:

```
  sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

my terminal cannot execute the command and simply gives me a new terminal prompt line. 
I am using node version 7.8.0 and npm version 4.2.0 . Any idea of what 's going on?

Comment: was npm installed with brew?

Comment: the first time yes. Now I am using NVM

Comment: ok.. just thought if so it might not actually need sudo

Comment: I've tried without sudo but it's still not working

Comment: do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: unfortunately no...it just returns a new prompt line...

Comment: added npm and nvm tags.. they may have a better idea

Comment: do you know how to install npm tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the *ionic* folder that was located in ..usr/local/lib/node_modules
and I've removed the *ionic* *alias* that was located in ..user/local/bin and I was able to do a new installation. Now I've installed ionic v 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try without the -g flag, and purge the package after.

```
npm uninstall ionic
apt-get purge npm
```

Comment: I've tried but  the system cannot recognize the apt-get purge npm command

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot mac uses HomeBrew now. Try "brew uninstall npm --force". My Mac knowledge is pretty limited just trying to give you a hand based on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete every trace of ionic under the nodejs folder and then run

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: Yes I did the same

Answer (score 0):

set your npm registry to main repo

```
sudo npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```